# How to reconcile stroke order with font variation on 衷?

Tags: kanji, stroke-order, stroke-count

From [Jisho.org](http://jisho.org/search/%E8%A1%B7%20%23kanji), the stroke order for 衷 (inmost, heart, mind, inside) is:

[image: First portion of stroke order for inmost]
[image: Second portion of stroke order for inmost]

I count 9 strokes, but the stroke number is listed there as 10. Additionally, on Android (*with* [kanji fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ascendtv.kanjifix&hl=en)), the kanji is rendered like this:

[image: Image of Android rendering of 衷]

The number of strokes and the Android font version seems inconsistent with the stroke order. What is the correct stroke order for this kanji? How can I reconcile these inconsistencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the jisho.org data is not always correct and comes from work by Jim Breen and [WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/wwwjdicinf.html). It's valiant work, but it also includes errors.

At least according to [kakijun.jp](http://kakijun.jp/page/09192200.html), this is primarily a ten stroke character.
According to kakijun, the top should be a 亠（ナベブタ）and then a mouth　口 with a stroke drawn through it. The nine-stroke version listed there is considered an alternative.

Comment: Technically, the stroke order diagrams on jisho come from KanjiVG, not the JDIC data.  See the about section of jiaho.org for more details.